# Trying to create a bootstrap carousel with vue js components

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, bootstrap-4, vue-component

I'm trying to implement a carousel in a Laravel project with Vue using mdb: https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/vue/advanced/carousel/

And I'm trying to convert each slide:

```
<mdb-carousel-item img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(68).jpg" mask="black-light" alt="First slide">
  <mdb-carousel-caption title="Light mask" text="First text"></mdb-carousel-caption>
</mdb-carousel-item>
```

Into a Vue component, like this:

```
<carouselitem picture="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(68).jpg" title="First slide" text="First text"></carouselitem>
```

So I have 2 components: carousel and carouselitem, and I call them from the Home component, where I want to implement the slider:

```
<template>
  <carousel>
    <carouselitem picture="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(68).jpg" title="First slide" text="First text"></carouselitem>
    <carouselitem picture="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(6).jpg" title="Second slide" text="Second text"></carouselitem>
    <carouselitem picture="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(9).jpg" title="Third slide" text="Third text"></carouselitem>
  </carousel>
<template>

<script>
import carousel from '../components/Carousel.vue';
import carouselitem from '../components/Carousel_item.vue';

export default {
  name: 'Index',
  components: {
    carousel,
    carouselitem
  }
}
</script>
```

This is the carousel component:

```
<template>
  <mdb-carousel :interval="8000" showControls showIndicators>
    <slot></slot>
  </mdb-carousel>
</template>

<script>
import { mdbCarousel, mdbCarouselItem, mdbCarouselCaption } from 'mdbvue';

export default {
  name: 'ThumbnailsCarouselPage',
  components: {
    mdbCarousel,
    mdbCarouselItem,
    mdbCarouselCaption
  }
}
</script>
```

And this is the carouselitem component:

```
<template>
  <mdb-carousel-item img v-bind:src="picture" mask="black-light" v-bind:alt="title">
    <mdb-carousel-caption v-bind:title="title" v-bind:text="text"></mdb-carousel-caption>
  </mdb-carousel-item>
</template>

<script>
import { mdbCarouselItem, mdbCarouselCaption } from 'mdbvue';

export default {
  name: 'carouselitem',
  props: ['picture','title','text'],
  components: {
    mdbCarouselItem,
    mdbCarouselCaption
  }
}
</script>
```

The problem now is that I can only see the first picture, it doesn't slide to the next one.

There are no errors in the console.

bootstrap-vue and mdbvue are properly installed.

It works OK when I just copy and paste the code from the mdb website, but not when I convert it into components.

Any ideas?

Comment: do you have any error in the browser console? inspecting the element via developer tools, can you see the text, maybe hidden?

Comment: Don't see any errors... That the most frustrating part. But there's this in the vue console:

thumbnailsSrc:Array[3]
0:undefined
1:undefined
2:undefined
//
In the data section.

Comment: what about setting a fixed text, like `title="this is a title"` instead of `v-bind:title`? does it get through the component?

Comment: Nope, setting fixed images and texts makes no difference :(